# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList inside ViewUserControl

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new with MVC and am stuck with this problem I have a ViewUserControl with a small contact form, I have created a mode for this ContactForm.

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type your Name"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string NameProperty { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type your Mobile"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Mobile")]
    public string MobileProperty { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type your City"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("City")]
    public string CityProperty { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Product"), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Product")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductProperty { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Type your Message"), DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [DisplayName("Message")]
    public string MessageProduct { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProductList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Printed Fabrics", Value = "1" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Silk  Fabrics", Value = "2" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Printed Silk Fabrics", Value = "3" });
        return items;
    }
```

inside ViewUserControl

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<govindHari.Models.ContactForm>" %>
```

Now how to call this inside

```
    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.CityProperty) %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CityProperty, new { @class = "textBox" })%>

    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.MobileProperty) %>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobileProperty, new { @class = "textBox" })%>

    <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductProperty) %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ProductProperty)%>
```

The problem is its not working for me, even if I send it from HomeController from Index Page

Please help
Regards

Answer (score 0):

It has start working after a simple change

> m.ProductProperty, (IEnumerable) Model.ProductProperty)%>